# Selenium testng.xml file compilation issue

Tags: selenium, testng

When i am trying to compile `testng.xml` file it is giving the following error

```
Error:(15, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method dependsOnMethod()
  location: @interface org.testng.annotations.Test
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include [minimal, complete and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide method in double quotes

```
  @Test(dependsOnMethods="loginTest")
```

or

```
   @Test (dependsOnMethods = { "loginTest" })
```

Comment: Please check the screenshot that i have posted

Comment: please help me here

Comment: are you installed testng? in eclipse Help->Marketplace->search and install. After update you maven project. then try

Comment: No i am using   intellij idea.

Comment: I think i got where the problem is . The Selenium webdriver that i installed does not contain testng jar file.The version is 3.141.59.

Comment: see selenium does not contains testng. you need to install it. also you need to use dependency in pom.xml

Comment: I am getting the output on executing testng.xml file  org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.selenium.test.ComparisonTest .

Answer (score 0):

You have written 'dependsOnMethod' instead of 'dependsOnMethods'. Please check